# Order of product of disjoint cycles

Tags: group-theory, permutations, permutation-cycles

I know the order of the product of disjoint cycles is their lcm. If both cycles are the same length, is this the order of their product or is lcm(x,x) not equal to x?

Comment: Yes, it is. Why do you have doubts? Perhaps you should do an explicit example yourself. This could convince you more than an answer saying "This is exactly as you say it should be".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We do have $\operatorname{lcm}(x,x)=x$. And we have that the order of the product of two disjoint cycles, both of length $x$, is equal to $x$. This is exactly as you say it should be.